# Is there a way to display the children labels in Google Charts' TreeMap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, treemap

I'm trying to create a TreeMap using Google Charts that not only shows the parent label along with the children's color breakdowns, but also the children's labels. I basically want this (save possible children coloration): [image]

I haven't found any online examples or questions on it, is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not sure that you can get exactly like the picture,
but if you want to show both the parent and child labels,
use option --> `maxDepth: 2`

note: duplicate child id's are not allowed,
here, object notation is used to provide a unique id,
but still display the same name on multiple nodes

```
{v: 'Rick0', f: 'Rick'}
{v: 'Rick1', f: 'Rick'}
```

where...
`v:` *=* value
`f:` *=* formatted value

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['treemap']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Person', 'Fruit', 'Size', 'Color'],
    ['Global', null, 0, 0],
    ['Bananas', 'Global', 0, 0],
    [{v: 'Rick0', f: 'Rick'}, 'Bananas', 100, 0],
    [{v: 'Anne0', f: 'Anne'}, 'Bananas', 40, 0],
    [{v: 'Peter0', f: 'Peter'}, 'Bananas', 5, 0],
    ['Apples', 'Global', 0, 0],
    [{v: 'Anne1', f: 'Anne'}, 'Apples', 20, 2],
    [{v: 'Peter1', f: 'Peter'}, 'Apples', 20, 2],
    [{v: 'Rick1', f: 'Rick'}, 'Apples', 15, 2],
    ['Oranges', 'Global', 0, 0],
    [{v: 'Rick2', f: 'Rick'}, 'Oranges', 20, 1],
    [{v: 'Peter2', f: 'Peter'}, 'Oranges', 20, 1],
    [{v: 'Anne2', f: 'Anne'}, 'Oranges', 10, 1],
    ['Susanne', 'Global', 10, null]
  ]);

  tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  tree.draw(data, {
    maxDepth: 2,
    minColor: 'yellow',
    midColor: 'orange',
    maxColor: 'red',
    noColor: 'lime',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: It does, thanks! It's not perfect, but I suspect it's the best the library can do, thanks!