# How do I add a hidden string to a google label graph for uniqueness?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap to make a sort of heat map of an organization.  The labels need to be first name last name... even if 2 people have the same name (don't as me why).

Problem: It seems like the google code needs the block labels to be unique, and all characters are visible ~ so I can't hide something unique in the label.

Has anyone run up against this puzzle?

Ideally I could label things like this `<span style="display:none;">uniqueness</span>Joe Dohn`

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613531/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat ... SWEET!!!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WhiteHat's comment yesterday lead to the solution.  I'll post it here because the solution they pointed out is not well related to the question as it is posted.  More like a small side detail included in the Q&A.

The treemap js takes json from the server and shows blocks with labels.  The label is also the unique-id linking the parent block to the child datas.  That json looks like this...

```
[
["TARGET", "PARENT", "SIZE", "COLOR"],
["Top", null, 0, 0],
["105::Vincent Tong", "Top", 276969, -67],
["106::David Chung", "Top", 0, 0],
["107::Beatrice Tao", "Top", 0, 0]
...
["8848::Michael Kim", "105::Vincent Tong", 276969, -67],
["7632::Del Rosario, Romelli & Rosemarie", "109::John Villamin", 290000, -67],
["5940::YUNNA WANG", "178::William Yu", 819000, -67]
...
]
```

Here you can see that Mr. Vincent Tong is identified as 105::Vincent Tong and that Vincent is the parent block of Michael Kim in the second block.  The prefix '105::' is used to create uniqueness, but also shows up in the ui as the block label.  To create a nice looking label but maintain uniquness we need an object instead of 123::FirstName LastName.  The json should look like this:

```
...
[{"v": "105::Vincent Tong","f": "Vincent Tong"}, "Top", 276969, -67],
...
```

In the second level, when Vincent is the parent, we keep the unique string but expand Michael to an object.

```
...
[{"v": "8848::Michael Kim","f": "Michael Kim"}, "105::Vincent Tong", 276969, -67]
...
```

BUG: I've used this on tree and sankey visualizations.  On tree the "f" value is the display label and the "v" is the hidden uniquness.  On sankey it's the opposite.